# Backslash in string from standard input, no way to stripe it

Tags: swift, string, stdin

I have a string that comes from the standard input in Xcode, using Swift. When I type in my string, I write something like this :

```
He told me "Hello maaan"
```

What I see when I print my message after putting a breakpoint is this :

```
"He told me \"Hello maaan""
```

Now, the quotes at the start and the end can be ignored, but what's that backslash? If I run this code in the console

```
po message.contains("\\")
```

it returns me `false`. The thing is that I need to run a regex on that string and the regex fails because of that `\` char. What's the solution?

**EDIT**

If I transform my string to a `NSString`, the console prints this :

```
He told me "Hello maaan
```

Comment: Most probably it is just the *debugger* who escapes the quotation marks in the string. Try `print(message)` in your program, and you should see that everything is fine.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that's absolutely true. But when the string is passed to my parser which performs the Regex match, it fails because of that backslash.

Comment: You can also try `expr -- print(message)` in the debugger window. – So the string does not contain backslashes, which means that the regex matching problem is caused by something else. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: It prints `He told me "Hello maaan` without the last double quotes.

Comment: If there is no backslash then you cannot remove it. If you have a problem parsing the string then please post the corresponding code: a *minimal self-contained* example. That example should start with `let message = #"He told me "Hello maaan""#` followed by your parsing code, and the expected and actual results.

Answer (score -1):

In order for the compiler to ignore the quotation marks you'll need to add the backslashes before both.

So, you'll need to format your string as so:

```
var string = " He told me: \"Hello Man\"."

print(string)
```

Comment: Martin, I revised my answer. It's just originally I found it difficult to even explain the solution with words.